# Python csv.writerow([]) across two lines?

Tags: python, csv

My code is:

```
c = csv.writer(open("addresses.csv",  "wb"), quoting=csv.QUOUTE_ALL)
temp = open("temp_address.txt") //this contains a string, like this "1234567890ABCDEF"
c.writerow([temp.read(), "customers withdraw"])
```

The .csv file ends out like this

```
"1234567890ABCDEF
","Customers widthraw"
```

Why does this happen? I would appreciate some help to fixing this

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the file has a newline at the end.  You might want to `.strip()` the results.

e.g.:

```
c.writerow([temp.read().strip(), "customers withdraw"])
```